# Getting parsing error in solr?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.6 and while indexing documents i could see couple of  errors/warnings in logs. I want to make sure  that despite these messages, will documents be indexed into solr or will they be skipped.

Finally can i upgrade relevant jars i.e. pdfbox and tika to resolve the issue without breaking anything else?

Error.

> ERROR PDCIDFont Error: Could not parse predefined CMAP file for '¢¬%?Â-ª¬/3Ó~Œ[-UCS2'
>
> Error: Could not parse predefined CMAP file for 'PDFAUTOCAD-Indentity0-UCS2'

Also i could see below warnings.

> ExtractingDocumentLoader
> skip extracting text due to TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser@37e5a2db. metadata=stream_source_info=TMSD SS_FI006 - Fixed Assets Course Slides.pptx stream_content_type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation stream_size=9780764 stream_name=TMSD SS_FI006 - Fixed Assets Course Slides.pptx Content-Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation resourceName=TMSD SS_FI006 - Fixed Assets Course Slides.pptx

And

> ExtractingDocumentLoader
> skip extracting text due to Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@6900efc8. metadata=stream_source_info=PMO IW Enduring Employees_Secondment Tracker.xlsx stream_content_type=application/x-tika-ooxml-protected stream_size=52736 custom:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid=9523d6bd-d1cf-40b5-b5b3-ca1ce43c4eb0 stream_name=PMO IW Enduring Employees_Secondment Tracker.xlsx custom:ContentTypeId=0x010100B98D2353323F5D4F8163D5A4670906C0 Content-Type=application/x-tika-ooxml-protected resourceName=PMO IW Enduring Employees_Secondment Tracker.xlsx

Comment: Yes, upgrading the jars should work. Try it.

Comment: I upgraded from pdfbox & fontbox 1.8.1 to 1.8.6 jars & i could see error gone but warnings still exist. Do i need to upgrade any other jars also?

Comment: We are also getting similar kind of exception. 
CustomExtractingDocumentLoader
skip extracting text due to TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@4f5cb2c5. metadata=stream_size=974355 X-Parsed-By=org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser X-Parsed-By=org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser stream_content_type=application/pdf stream_name=Report_Badylak-08.22.20192.pdf stream_source_info=file Content-Type=application/pdf